# Apache returning 403 status code along with page content

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directoryindex

I have a cPanel hosting account with my primary domain pointing to `public_html`. But, to make directory structure better, I add the following code to `public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www\.MyDomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MyDomain.www/$1 [NC,L]
```

It simply redirect all request from `/public_html` to `/public_html/MyDomain.www` for my primary domain.

But, the problem is when I visit `http://www.MyDomain.com/` it dispays page at `public_html/MyDomain.www/index.php` but with 403 HTTP code instead of 200 which is expected. Note, visiting `http://www.MyDomain.com/index.php` returns page correctly with 200 HTTP code.

So, How can I fix the 403 error code?

Comment: Can any help me  about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replacing the existing rewrite rule in .htaccess with this and surprisingly it worked.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domain.www/
RewriteRule (.*) /domain.www/$1 [L]
```